# Why is this foreach not saving? Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a join between to tables and then am looking to change 2 values and save each record with this join.

```
foreach ($data as $datas) {
     $datas->dealerCode = $datas->dealer;
     $datas->owner = 'K';

     $datas->save();
}
```

I am able to get the records in a collection (`$data`) but can't seem to save.  The fields I am looking to update are fillable in the model.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

$datas is;

```
 Collection {#446 ▼
      #items: array:12 [▼
    0 => Consumer {#447 ▼
      #fillable: array:35 [▶]
      #guarded: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:59 [▼
        "id" => 512
        "pin" => 0
        "campaignCode" => "Test"
        "campaignId" => 7
        "eventCode" => "Test"
        "eventLocation" => "Testville"
        "rsvp" => 0
        "attendance" => 1
        "appended" => 0
        "salutation" => "Mr."
        "firstName" => "K E"
        "lastName" => "Test"
        "email" => "test@test.com"
        "postal" => "x1x1x1"
        "address1" => "7493 Amber Grounds"
        "address2" => ""
        "city" => "Hardscrabble"
        "province" => "MB"
        "language" => "en"
        "dealerCode" => ""
        "created_at" => "2015-09-11 14:20:36"
        "updated_at" => "2016-01-18 15:38:53"
        "dealer" => "11111"
      ]
      #original: array:59 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
    1 => Consumer {#448 ▶}
    2 => Consumer {#449 ▶}
    3 => Consumer {#450 ▶}
    4 => Consumer {#451 ▶}
    5 => Consumer {#452 ▶}
    6 => Consumer {#453 ▶}
    7 => Consumer {#454 ▶}
    8 => Consumer {#455 ▶}
    9 => Consumer {#456 ▶}
    10 => Consumer {#457 ▶}
    11 => Consumer {#458 ▶}
  ]
}
```

print_r($datas) gives me;

```
App\Consumer Object
(
[fillable:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => salutation
        [1] => firstName
        [2] => lastName
        [3] => email
        [4] => postal
        [5] => phone
        [6] => address1
        [7] => address2
        [8] => city
        [9] => province
        [24] => dealerCode
    )

[guarded:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => id
        [1] => created_at
    )

[connection:protected] => 
[table:protected] => 
[primaryKey:protected] => id
[perPage:protected] => 15
[incrementing] => 1
[timestamps] => 1
[attributes:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => 512
        [pin] => MA61151A7
        [campaignCode] => 101400101
        [campaignId] => 7
        [eventCode] => Test
        [eventLocation] => Testville
        [rsvp] => 0
        [attendance] => 1
        [appended] => 0
        [salutation] => Mr.
        [firstName] => K E
        [lastName] => Test
        [email] => test@test.com
        [postal] => X1X1X1
        [address1] => 7493 Amber Grounds
        [address2] => 
        [city] => Hardscrabble
        [province] => MB
        [language] => en
        [dealerCode] => 
        [dealer] => 11111
    )

[original:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => 512
        [pin] => MA61151A7
        [campaignCode] => 101400101
        [campaignId] => 7
        [eventCode] => Test
        [eventLocation] => Testville
        [rsvp] => 0
        [attendance] => 1
        [appended] => 0
        [salutation] => Mr.
        [firstName] => K E
        [lastName] => Test
        [email] => test@test.com
        [postal] => X1X1X1
        [address1] => 7493 Amber Grounds
        [address2] => 
        [city] => Hardscrabble
        [province] => MB
        [language] => en
        [dealerCode] => 
        [dealer] => 11111
    )
```

Consumer model;

```
protected $fillable = [
    'salutation',
    'firstName',
    'lastName',
    'email',
    'postal',
    'phone',
    'address1',
    'address2',
    'city',
    'province',
    'owner',
];
```

Incidentally, this is how it works in mySql;

```
update consumers c
join owners o
on c.email = o.email
set c.owner = 'K'
```

Here is the full function from my Controller;

```
public function setOwner()
{
        $data = Consumer::join('owners', 'consumers.email', '=', 'owners.email')
            ->where('consumers.eventCode', '=', 'Test')->get();

    foreach ($data as $datas) {
        $obj = Consumer::find($datas['id']);
        //$obj = empty($obj) ? new Consumer : $obj;
        // $obj = new Consumer;
        $obj->dealerCode = $datas['dealer'];
        $obj->owner = 'K';
        $obj->save();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your MODEL name In which you are trying to save data?

Comment: The model is Consumer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "can't seem to save" ? You're checking the db and the new values are not updated there? Can you show the schema for your db table?

Comment: your first dump of $datas is a Collection? Or ist this wrong and you meant a dump of $data ?

Comment: Sorry, yes the dump is $data, its a collection or collections.

Comment: i have tried your setup and it works... can you provide the code of your Consumer Model ?

Comment: i  meant the "whole" model .. if it is too large, use pastebin or something similar. The problem has nothing to do with $fillable

Comment: Do you mean my controller?  That's all there is in the model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101112/discussion-between-shock-gone-wild-and-tenz).

Answer (score 4):

you have to create new object in every step of loop

```
foreach ($data as $datas) {
        $datas = new Datas();
        $datas->dealerCode = $datas->dealer;
        $datas->owner = 'K';
        $datas->save();
    }
```

Comment: This is giving me Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Datas' not found error.

Comment: Datas() is a dummy class name.User your class name instead of Datas()

Comment: Ah.  Should have know that.

so now getting

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'dealerCode' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `consumers` (`dealerCode`, `owner`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, K, 2016-01-19 09:14:11, 2016-01-19 09:14:11))

Comment: the value for dealer is coming from my join.  Do I need to specify the table?  Like - $datas->table.dealer;

Comment: first print the dealerCode upper foreach for check is that exists dealerCode then save within foreach

Comment: this makes no sense... you are overwriting $datas with a new eloquent instance

Comment: This is creating a new object. Instead, he wanted each of the objects to be updated using the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data as &$datas) {
        $datas->dealerCode = $datas->dealer;
        $datas->owner = 'K';

        $datas->save();
    }
```

Just pass & before $database.
$data will be updated.

Comment: Hmm, never seen that before.  Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Right, any idea what might?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
foreach ($data as $datas) {
     $obj = Consumer::find($datas['id']);
     //$obj = empty($obj) ? new Consumer : $obj;
     // $obj = new Consumer;
     $obj->dealerCode = $datas['dealer'];
     $obj->owner = 'K';
     $obj->save();
}
```

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: Well yes that works but it is creating a new record.  I am trying to update a record from my join.

Comment: So $data is a collection of Consumers.

Comment: In this instance it made a new record for every Consumer in the table.

Comment: Okay. I get it. Give me your $datas.

Comment: Please see my updated answer and let me know is it working or not?

Comment: Getting - Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Your Consumer model is in [0] key. Just try to get it. Try to get "id" => 512. Write echo '<pre>'; print_r($datas); and show your output in question.

Comment: No error but it is creating a new record for each.  I am trying to update existing records.

Comment: Very strange. Try now. I have commented 2 lines in answer.

Comment: Now I get Creating default object from empty value